# How to use one row in a table to indicate a directory path

Tags: python, pandas, directory, shutil

I have one table with 2 columns(string) and each row represents a folder name in my computer. The column 1 represents a folder x and the column 2 is another folder inside the x.
I would like to use this table in a script that brings me the directory of these folders.
For exemple:

column 1     column 2
folder x     folder A
folder y     folder B

The script would bring the directory:
C:\Users...\folder x\folder A
C:\User...\folder y\folder B

I'm trying to use the following code:
shutil.copy2('C:\users...\folder x\folder A','C:\Users....')

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by table, if it is a database or a CSV file or something completely different. But let us assume that you know how to access the data in a row of a table and how to put it in the variables. Now you can simply join the paths using:

```
import os

# Replace this with the actual data fetching from the table.
val_col_1 = "folder_x"
val_col_2 = "folder_A"

joined_dir = os.path.join(val_col_1, val_col_2)
```

`joined_dir` will be the joined path `"folder_x\\folder_A"`. `os.join.path` is not restricted to only two arguments, you can provide as many as you want. If for example all your paths have the same prefix `"C:\User"` you could do

```
joined_dir = os.path.join("C:\User" ,val_col_1, val_col_2)
```

This will produce the string `"C:\\User\\folder_x\\folder_A"`.